# Issue with array_map callback

Tags: php, array-map

At first I had this (work in wamp but not in my web server)

```
$ids = array_map(function($item) { return $item['user_id']; }, $data['student_teacher']);`
```

So I try to convert the code to that but nothing work ( i got Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array from outpout )

```
$ids = array_map($this->myarraymap(null), $data['student_teacher']);

function myarraymap($item) {
        return $item['user_id']; 

    }
```

Comment: This is PHP-specific, not CodeIgniter-specific issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass it a callback, and not actually pass it the execution of the function, i.e.,

```
$ids = array_map(array($this, 'myarraymap'), $data['student_teacher']);

function myarraymap($item) {
   return $item['user_id']; 
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked. Don't forget to accept answers if you found them helpful :D